# Connection appears accepted server-side but appears to be refused in my python script

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a python script I am running to add a document to a collection for a remote mongodb database. The file is as follows:

```
from pymongo import Connection
ip    = 'x.x.x.x' #edited out

conn  = Connection()
db    = conn['netmon']

users = db.users
print 'number of users: ' + str(users.count())
if users.count() == 0:
  print 'Please create a new account.'
  t_user = raw_input('Username:')
  users.insert({'username':unicode(t_user)})
conn.close()
```

When I run this script, I have some interesting behavior. In the server logs, it appears that the connection is accepted, the query is run, and then the connection is closed.

```
# Mongodb logs
14:27:18 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 108.93.46.75:39558 #1
14:27:18 [conn1] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
14:27:18 [conn1] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 reslen:71 0ms
14:27:18 [conn1] run command netmon.$cmd { count: "users", fields: null, query: {} }
14:27:18 [conn1] Accessing: netmon for the first time
14:27:18 [conn1] command netmon.$cmd command: { count: "users", fields: null, query: {} } ntoreturn:1 reslen:58 10ms
14:27:18 [conn1] end connection 108.93.46.75:39558
```

However, this is what I get from the python script:

```
# Python error
> python testmongo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmongo.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn  = Connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.__find_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 586, in __find_node
    raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
charles@charles-mbp:~/Desktop$ python testmongo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmongo.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn  = Connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.__find_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 586, in __find_node
    raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
charles@charles-mbp:~/Desktop$ python testmongo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmongo.py", line 7, in <module>
    conn  = Connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 290, in __init__
    self.__find_node()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymongo/connection.py", line 586, in __find_node
    raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Some useful information:
The remote server is a VPS running on OpenVZ. I know there are compatibility problems related to count() and iterators, but I (assumingly) fixed them by using the --smallfiles option, as well as limiting my nssize to 100. My firewall on both sides are completely open.

I've also noticed that in the errors, autoreconnect is trying to connect to localhost, even though I specified a different IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the IP - `conn = Connection(ip)`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that. I kept running into error after error, and only made this change after fixing the OpenVZ memory problems. Thank you.